# How to show a card after a specified interval in app

Tags: flutter, dart, future, duration, dayofweek

I want to show the card on the main page once a week in my app.

Can anyone help me how can I do that?

I use `Future.delayed` in the init state and set duration "7 days" for it.

But I think it is wrong.

So how can I do that?

```
void initState() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(days: 7), () {
   showBottomSheet(context);
     }); 
 super.initState();
}
```

Comment: You need to use SharedPreferences or other local storage to handle this thing.

Comment: Maybe store the starting date and check at the start of the app if it is 7 days after?

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing

> get weekday and set a condition on that like

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
print("weekday is ${date.weekday}");
if date.weekday == MONDAY {
      do task for Monday
}else {do task for other day.. }
```

> this will very simple and easy away to trigger event on a specific day like sale on frieday or movie offer on Sunday..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [**`Timer.run`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/run.html) refer [**`Timer`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html),

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.run(() {
      Future.delayed(Duration(days: 7), () {
         showBottomSheet(context);//This function display after every 7 Days
      });
    });    
   }
```

Comment: Do you think that the user having the app in the foreground for 7 days straight for this to work is a realistic option?

Comment: @nvoigt I think

Comment: @nvoigt this won't run for 7 foreground, as the mobile OS will prevent any background process if its more than 18 seconds to each application (there's a way to handle it but it's not a straight forward task)

Comment: @Unna I know, that was a rhetorical question, obviously this answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show the card on the main page Once a week in my app. can anyone help me how can I do that?

You cannot do that without persisting data. Anything you do purely in your app will be gone when the user closes your app, moves it to the background of their mobile operating system or puts their device into standby.

Save the date and time you want it to appear somewhere. [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) would be one option, a backend API or the FireStore would be another.

When your app starts, read that date from the store and find out if it's time to show your banner. Alternatively, if you suspect your app is open for a long time and you want it to appear spontanously, set a [timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to run this check periodically while your app is running.

Once you have shown the banner, add the next date to show it to the data store you picked.